# Use of might rather than might have

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

Let's look at the context.

Would you go if she called you?

Yeah. I *might* go.

Is it correct to use 'might' here rather than 'might have'? I think here 'might' is used as the past form of 'may'. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct to use **might**.

It's a way of saying: **Yes I might go if she called me.

**Might have** is a short form of **might have gone**.

This answer would be correct if the question had been:

> Would you have gone if she had called you?
> Yes, I might have (gone).

This is a question in the **hypothetical past** - what might have happened if a situation had arisen. You will find lots of examples if you google it.

Comment: The sentence 'would you go if she called you' is a conditional sentence that refers to the present we are imagining. Right?

Comment: I doubt the OP was asking about the hypothetical past, rather about the "might have to" form. Otherwise you are totally right in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between

- I might go.
- I might have to go.

Is the following:

1. I might go - Means that there is a possibility that I will go.
2. I might have to go - Means that there might occur a reason for me to go.

Comment: The first implies whether you go is your choice.  The second implies whether you go is not your choice.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Right, but not all right! In the second sentence you still have a choice not to go although you have to.